# How should I store my API key on Heroku so that it still stays secret instead of embedding in web page code

Tags: heroku, api-key

I have built a Flak app, locally I have stored it as environment variable, but I do not know how should I store my API key on Heroku so that it still stays secret instead of embedding in web page code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your api-key as environment variables as these are perfectly secure:

go to you local folder and run `heroku config:set key_one=value_one key_two=value_two` and more.

Note: run above commands in the same folder which points to your repository.

once you set the environment variable you can access this key value pair in you code directly as:

`var api_key = process.env.key_one;`

Answer (score 1):

You can also easily add or edit your config variables from your heroku app’s Settings tab, look [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard) at Heroku's official documentation.